# Only accept 4 character long, decimal numbers as user input for read

Tags: linux, bash, shell, decimal, posix

I am writing a small script to easily capture weights, which are taken from user input with `read -p`.

I want all captured weights to be 4 characters long, **decimal numbers** in the format **XX.X**. For example **30.2** kg.

```
#!/bin/bash

# take input from prompt (-p) and store it in $varweight
read -p 'Enter weight in kg: ' varweight
```

How can I make sure users can only input decimal numbers in that format?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: And if the weight is < 10 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use a regex and assert the length to remove false positives (optionally). Of course the below would require the `bash` shell because the `~` is not POSIX compliant

```
str="30.4"
re='^[[:digit:]]{2}\.[[:digit:]]$'

if [[ $str =~ $re ]]; then
    echo 'true'
fi
```

On a POSIX compliant shell though you could use `case` statement

```
case $str in  
   [0-9][0-9].[0-9]) echo good ;; 
   *) echo bad;; 
esac
```

A much better POSIX compliant tool would be to use `expr` to do the regex match.

```
if expr "$str" : '[[:digit:]]\{2\}\.[[:digit:]]$' > /dev/null; then
    echo "true"
fi
```

Comment: Use `expr` to validate `str` rather than breaking it in half and checking the length of each component (which does not weed out invalid inputs like `xy.z`). `if expr "$str" : '[[:digit:]]\{2\}\.[[:digit:]]$' > /dev/null; then`.

Comment: @chepner: Is if condition with `((..))` POSIX compliant too? I think so

Comment: Nope. POSIX has arithmetic expressions (`$((...))`), but not the arithmetic compound command (`((...))`).

Comment: The `case` statement is fine; as an aside, the `.` doesn't need to be escape, as it has no special meaning in a pattern.